# Gradle module output configuration for test dependencies only

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-dependencies

I have a *Gradle* project containing the two modules `app` and `test`, where `test` contains utilities for testing only. Now I'd like to setup this module, so it doesn't include any outputs into the *main* configuration of `app`; even not accidentally.

```
implementation project(':test') # should fail or not contain any inputs

testImplementation project(':test') # should include all inputs
androidTestImplementation project(':test') # should include all inputs
```

How do I configure `test` to behave like this?

I'd assume it would be similarly to how the *Android* plugin handles configurations for build types and flavors, but I'm also not sure on how to figure this out.

I think these are handled with [*Gradle* consumer attributes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_attribute_based_matching.html). Maybe there's a filter or an attribute which could be applied to it to make it only available to tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`java-test-fixtures`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures) plugin almost behaves like I wished, just a bit more verbose.

```
implementation project(':test') # should fail or not contain any inputs

testImplementation testFixtures(project(':test'))
androidTestImplementation testFixtures(project(':test'))
```

#### Some other downsides for now

As Tom Tresansky [Is the java-test-fixtures plugin incompatible with the Build and run using IntelliJ IDEA setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963413/is-the-java-test-fixtures-plugin-incompatible-with-the-build-and-run-using-intel) asked and answered, the *Android Studio* doesn't handle the `testFixtures` source set well.

Also it is not yet available for *Kotlin* or *Android*. But as [Michael Evans pointed out](http://michaelevans.org/blog/2019/09/21/stop-repeating-yourself-sharing-test-code-across-android-modules/), there's tasks already open for [Android](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139438142) and on [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-33877).

But creating the test fixtures with a *Kotlin* JVM project and consuming these with an *Android* project works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use annotations for that:
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations#visible

Another way would be exclude testing code to new module named as `sub_test` and use `testImplementation` or `androidTestImplementation` of that `sub_test` module in your `test` module

Comment: Of course I could do this, but I'm looking for a configuration that helps me to prevent that it accidentally happens. Something similar to how the build variants work.

Answer (score 0):

Found: [Use separate test modules for instrumented tests](https://developer.android.com/studio/test#use_separate_test_modules_for_instrumented_tests), which tells the how to do it:

> ... apply the `com.android.test` plugin instead of `com.android.library`.

Comment: Just imagine test fixture, fakes or dummies you implement to be consumed by any given test. It is not about the tests itself. I think I might be looking into _Gradle consumer attributes_. I'll update the question.

Comment: @tynn the issue is, that unit & instrumentation tests have little in common - therefore it would barely add duplicate code to the project, if you'd add the one kind of tools into the one source-set and the other kind into the other source-set. adding stuff into there which are no tests is perfectly legal; eg. custom `ViewMatcher`. The main problem is still the namespace ...because it builds the test application per module - which somehow defeats your concept. And I can understand the motivation to some degree, but nevertheless the test framework is the imperative.

Comment: The dependencies for the unit or instrumentation are not really my concern. Any other module or artifact would work. I just want to make sure to not leak any dependency module into the main code. Also, on a theoretical side, I'd like to know how to configure Gradle to export a dependencies for test specifically. You already have this for build variants. But why stop there.