# Is the java-test-fixtures plugin incompatible with the Build and run using IntelliJ IDEA setting?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, java-test-fixtures

It looks like if I use the java-test-fixtures plugin in my java Gradle project, when IntelliJ imports it the IDE will always mark the `src/testFixtures` dir as a Source Folder (visible in Module Settings, Sources tab).

Yet any dependencies I've added in my `build.gradle` to the `testFixturesApi` or `testFixturesImplementation` configurations are imported into the IDEA project with a Scope of `Test` (visible in Module Settings, Dependencies tab).

So when I go to build my Project, using the Project Build and run using setting of `IntelliJ IDEA` instead of the default of `Gradle` (visible in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle), the builder can't find the deps from those testFixtures configurations and I get a bunch of package does not exist errors.

This behaviour can easily be reproduced after setting up a new `java-library` project using the `gradle init` wizard and adding the 'java-test-fixtures' plugin to it, then adding a dep to one of the test fixtures configuration and importing it in a java file in the test fixtures SourceSet, then switching the Build and run setting and clicking build.

I'm using Gradle 6.0 and IntelliJ 2019.3 BETA.

I've tried explicitly marking the testFixtures source dir as a Test Source folder:

```
idea {
    module {
        testSourceDirs += project.sourceSets.testFixtures.allJava.srcDirs
    }
}
```

But the IDEA Gradle import doesn't seem to honor this, and I suspect it's the wrong solution anyway.

Is there any way to get the java-test-fixtures plugin to play nice with the IDEA builder without leaking my deps from `testFixturesApi` configuration into the `api` configuration?

**UPDATE**

So my team has enabled the "gradle.settings.showDeprecatedSettings" option in the IntelliJ registry and is currently **NOT** using the recommended "Module per SourceSet" option - instead we have a module per project.  This issue only applies with module per project, which is deprecated.  See: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-222172

Comment: Might be a bug. Is it possible to have a sample project?

Comment: Sample project is easy to create, just 1) use gradle-init to create a new project 2) apply the plugin, 3) add a testFixtureApi dep, 4) import into IntelliJ and you'll see the problem.  2 minutes, tops.

Comment: More info on that option here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37018567/why-my-gradle-projects-creates-separated-modules-for-main-and-test-in-intellij-i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've found a workaround:

Add a new configuration:

```
configurations {
  ideaTestFixturesApi
}
```

Make the existing testFixturesApi configuration extend your new configuration:

```
configurations.testFixturesApi.extendsFrom(ideaTestFixturesApi)
```

Migrate all your dependencies from `testFixturesApi` -> `ideaTestFixturesApi`, at this point your Gradle build should once again run, and your IntelliJ build should remain broken in the same manner as before.

Apply the `idea` Gralde plugin and switch the scope of the new configuration to test

```
plugins {
   id 'idea'
}

// ...

idea {
    module {
       scopes.COMPILE.plus += [configurations.ideaTestFixturesApi]
    }
}
```

And then when you refresh your project via the Gradle view, you'll see every dep marked as `COMPILE` scope, which should allow the IntelliJ build to succeed.  You can do the same thing for `testFixturesImplementation`.

Less than ideal, but as there doesn't seem to be any way to force the `testFixtures` sourceSet to show up as a test source directory, this is the workaround I'm going with for now.

Comment: Nice solution. I defined the `ideaTestFixturesApi { extendsFrom testFixturesApi; canBeConsumed false; canBeResolved true }` and just kept using `testFixturesApi` to declare the dependencies. _ideaTestFixturesApi_ is basically a resolvable version of _testFixturesApi_ then.